# Как выровнять элементы в строке, если между ними находится текст

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет!
Есть строка в которой находится строчные элементы и между ними текст. Текст может динамически меняться. Как сделать так чтобы при изменении текста элементы не сдвигались в лева и в право а находились на одном месте, в независимости от длины текста между ними.

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="+7">Россия</option>
        <option value="+375">Белоруссия</option>
    </select>
    <span id="country_code_label"></span>
    <input type="text" name="phone"> //Этот элемент будет сдвигаться, если в country_code_label будет текст разной длины. Нужно его как то зафиксировать. 
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода вашей строки.

Comment: задать ширину inline элементов https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/u0pvomca/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта:

> 1) Длина строки известна - **можно задать ширину для кода страны** и
>   выровнять в нужную сторону(вправо например)

Но

> 2) Логичнее и проще вставить этот код в сам input с помощью
>   маски([смотри пример](http://codepen.io/Zentro/pen/WxJpab))

Таким образом можно произвести валидацию на клиенте, избежать проверок на правильность на бэк-е, проще распарсить строку.

Еще нужен скрипт реагирующий на смену select-а.

```js
$('.div2 input').mask(" (+375) 999-99-99");
```

```css
#country_code_label {
  display: inline-block;
  width : 3em;
  text-align: right;
}

.div1 {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
    <select>
        <option value="+7">Россия</option>
        <option value="+375">Белоруссия</option>
    </select>
    <span id="country_code_label">+375</span>
    <input type="text" name="phone"> <!--Этот элемент будет сдвигаться, если в country_code_label будет текст разной длины. Нужно его как то зафиксировать. -->
</div>
<div class='div2'>
    <div>
       <h2>Можно так же повесить маску на ввод</h2>
      <h3>И менять код для страны при изменении select-а</h3>
    </div>
    <select>
        <option value="+7">Россия</option>
        <option value="+375">Белоруссия</option>
    </select>
<!--     <span id="country_code_label"></span> -->
    <input type="text" name="phone"> <!--Этот элемент будет сдвигаться, если в country_code_label будет текст разной длины. Нужно его как то зафиксировать. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

как-то так наверное:

```css
#country_code_label{
          display:inline-block;
          max-width:30px;
          min-width:30px;
          overflow:hidden;
          
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="+7">Россия</option>
        <option value="+375">Белоруссия</option>
    </select>
    <span id="country_code_label">sergargaergaergaergaer</span>
    <input type="text" name="phone"> //Этот элемент будет сдвигаться, если в country_code_label будет текст разной длины. Нужно его как то зафиксировать. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если решать в лоб, то вам нужны `position: relative` для родительского `<div>` и `position: absolute` для `<input>`.